# How to write a T-Sql query that would output 1 if the value in a column in Table A matches the value in a column in Table B, 0 otherwise?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, match

I am using SQL Server 2012 and I need to write a query that would do give me the following output:

```
Code       Value
FRBAR        0
ENSPA        1
DEWINE       1
     ...
```

To achieve the above, I am working with 2 specific tables in my database, namely Table A and Table B. Table A has a column called `CodeA` and Table B has a column called `CodeB`.

I want to write a T-sql query that would match all the values in column `CodeA` with those in column `CodeB` and ouput the result I mentioned above.

I know I need to do a `JOIN` on these 2 columns but I am confused about how to implement the logic of returning a 1 if there is a match and a 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT CASE 
          WHEN CodeA IS NOT NULL THEN CodeA
          ELSE CodeB
       END AS Code,
       CASE 
          WHEN CodeA IS NOT NULL AND CodeB IS NOT NULL THEN 0
          ELSE 1
       END AS Value
FROM TableA
FULL OUTER JOIN TableB ON CodeA = CodeB
```

If there is a match the query will output `1` as `Value`. Otherwise the query will output `0` along with the not null code value.

**Note:** Using a `LEFT JOIN` will check *only in one direction*, i.e. only for codes in one table that don't exist in the other table. If you want to check *in both directions*, then you have to use a `FULL JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to take all records from `TableA` even then there is no matching records from `TableB` and then use `case-when-else` structure relying on absence(checking `is NULL`) of `TableB` part of resulting record.

```
select TableA.CodeA Code, 
case when
TableB.CodeB is null then 0
else 1
end Value
from TableA left outer join TableB on TableA.CodeA = TableB.CodeB
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN`. This will match the two tables on `Code` column and return `NULL` if there is no match. You can then use `CASE` to return 0 or 1 accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `CASE` and `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT A.codeA code, 
       CASE WHEN B.codeB IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.codeA = B.codeB
```